# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put the messages in the website using innerHTML.

```
function showRoomMessages(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var allMessages = document.getElementById('chat');
    allMessages.innerHTML = "";
    response.forEach(function (message){
        allMessages.innerHTML += "<div class='message'>" + message.description+ "<br>" + "verstuurd om: " + message.created_at + " door: " + message.user.name+"</div>";
    });
}
```

The response is an object filled with messages and message info.

Comment: What is `response`?

Comment: Can you show what is response?

Comment: So response is not an array....

Comment: I added information about response

Comment: If `response` is an object, you cannot use `forEach`. `forEach` is a method from the Array class.

Comment: `forEach` is a method available for arrays, and some array-like objects (like a NodeList). If `response` isn't one of them, you'll have to iterate through it differently.

Knowing the structure of `response` would help find the solution.

Comment: Is it an array or an object, if it's an object try `Object.keys(response).forEach`

Comment: Objects don't have a `forEach` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your response is an object and not an array, to loop through an object you can use `Object.keys()`

Example:

```
   Object.keys(response).forEach(function (key){
        allMessages.innerHTML += "<div class='message'>" + response[key].description+ "<br>" + "verstuurd om: " + response[key].created_at + " door: " + response[key].user.name+"</div>";
    });
```

Also note i now use `response[key]` to access the value of the object key.